# Reasoner's explanations on inconsistency

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning

I am using the code of the owlexplanation project by Matthew Horridge on GitHub.
I get the following reasoner inconsistency explanation. Could you please tell me why is that? My range is betwwen 4-9 and i gave the number 5.What is the inconsistency?

```
  [Explanation <SubClassOf(owl:Thing owl:Nothing)>
        DataPropertyRange(<http://www.semanticweb.org/katerina/ontologies/2015/3/farm2fork#test_dataProperty2> DataRangeRestriction(xsd:int facetRestriction(maxExclusive "9"^^xsd:int) facetRestriction(minExclusive "4"^^xsd:int)))
        DataPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/katerina/ontologies/2015/3/farm2fork#test_dataProperty2> <http://www.semanticweb.org/katerina/ontologies/2015/3/farm2fork#meat_002> "5")
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no type tag on "5" data value. I don't remember what is the default type but it is likely to be String. String and "int" are disjoint datatypes in OWL 2 DL, so the inconsistency. You can try to fix this problem by replacing "5" with "5"^^xsd:int

Comment: Indeed, that's an untyped literal (PlainLiteral or rdf:langString, depending on RDF 1.0 or 1.1). Its datatype is incompatible with any of the numeric datatypes, even if the literal form is identical to valid integer literals.